# method's arguments not being passed to decorator

Tags: python, decorator

hey I have a method defined as follows:

```
from x.y import util
class my_Class(some_object):
    @util.myDecorator
    def foo(self, log_file):
    '''
    Test that search entered into the search bar is the search being
    executed in the job.
    '''
    self.some_page.open()
    textarea = self.some_page.searchbar

    searchbar.run_search(log_file.search_string)
    self.browser.capture_screenshot()
    self.some_page.jobstatus.wait_for_job_complete()

    self.verify_equals(
        self.some_page.jobstatus.event_count,
        log_file.event_count,
        "Event count doesn't seem to be right.")
```

the decorator is in the file util.py

```
def mydecorator(func):
    def timeit(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.time()
        ret=func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.time()
        print end_time - start_time
        return ret
    return timeit
```

when i try executing the code, it fails at `ret=func(*args, **kwargs)` with the error message

> TypeError: foo() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

- I printed the contents of *args (with `','.join(str(each) for each in args)`) to see what it contained, and it printed out

> <....my_Class object at ...>

the decorator works fine for methods with just one arg (self) . Am i missing something here?

Comment: how do you invoke `foo` method? my_Class().foo()?

Comment: How are you actually calling `foo()`? This works: `my_Class().foo(123)`.  This doesn't: `my_Class().foo()`.

Comment: am using py.test to invoke the method foo

`py.test -k foo file_name.py`

Comment: If you're using pytest, you have to add parameters to those tests...

Comment: please provide complete failing pytest example. do you have more than one decorated function?

Comment: @alko - Yes i have multiple decorated methods. the pytest executes the test method and they pass when the number of args for the test method is just one! i.e. `self`, printing out the time taken for them to execute (end_time - start_time). but they fail when there are more args, other than `self`

Also are you asking for the test code? if so, see above, I have edited the foo method.

Comment: I'm not interested in foo code, but from the way you invoke tests (3rd comment) and from your code can't find any place where log file param is coming from, hence can't find out why it is working without arg itself. your decorator do not preserve function name, doc etc that can be potentially some source of errors when more than one func is decorated in a class

Answer (score 0):

Whiele you answer comments, be aware that it works:

```
>>> import time
>>>
>>> def mydecorator(func):
...     def timeit(*args, **kwargs):
...         start_time = time.time()
...         ret=func(*args, **kwargs)
...         end_time = time.time()
...         print end_time - start_time
...         return ret
...     return timeit
...
>>> class my_Class(object):
...     @mydecorator
...     def foo(self, arg_1):
...         print arg_1
...
>>> my_Class().foo(100)
100
0.0
```

Comment: this works for me too. but, as mentioned in the above comment, I am trying to invoke this method foo (viz. a test) using py.test

`py.test -k foo file_name.py`

Comment: but what `arg_1` you suppose pytest will pass to foo?

Comment: it is a log file. the log file is passed without any hiccups when i don't use the decorator. I tried using this decorator on several other tests with more than 1 arg. I am getting the same error.